# Looping animated vector drawable with multiple objectAnimator

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, vector-graphics, android-splashscreen

I created an animated vector drawable to use in Splash Screen API. I need to load data while splash screen is playing. However, sometimes data is loading slowly and I need to repeat splash screen animation.

I researched my problem on stackoverflow, `android:repeatCount="infinite" android:repeatMode="restart"` does not work because it is only applicable to objectAnimator. In my case I have multiple sets of object animators and when I try to repeat them, they repeat individually immediately after playing, not waiting for other other objectAnimators to finish. This breaks my animation.
Here is my AVD:

```
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
    <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
        <vector
            ...
        </vector>
    </aapt:attr>
    <target android:name="path_2">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:startOffset="300"
                    android:duration="300"
                    android:valueFrom=""
                    android:valueTo=""
                    android:valueType="pathType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:startOffset="900"
                    android:duration="300"
                    android:valueFrom=""
                    android:valueTo=""
                    android:valueType="pathType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:startOffset="300"
                    android:duration="300"
                    android:valueFrom=""
                    android:valueTo=""
                    android:valueType="pathType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:startOffset="900"
                    android:duration="300"
                    android:valueFrom=""
                    android:valueTo=""
                    android:valueType="pathType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```